# How to get the text of a website using C#?

Tags: c#, text, web

I'm trying to get the text out of a website without any source code.

I have this code:

```
HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
myRequest.Method = "GET";
WebResponse myResponse = myRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream(), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
sr.Close();
myResponse.Close();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Which of course will give me the text but also the source code as well. How shall I dispose of the source code?

Comment: What is "the text of a website"?

Comment: I can only guess the OP is looking to get the text that would be displayed from the body if viewed in a browser, minus markup and non-text entities (images, scripts, form elements).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using an HTML parser like the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex) - once the document is loaded to it you can extract the text from the top node using its `InnerText` property.

Comment: Yes, I saw another post with almost the same question but when I tried it, it didn't work..

Do you think you could give me an example?

When I get the whole source of a website it includes <div>.. <td>..<th>.. <p> and so on.
How do I use the Html Agility Pack to remove all that when I store the content in my string "result"
So when I finally read "result" it would only say the words on the website.

Comment: @MagnusGlannefors - Did you use the `InnerText` property as I described?

Comment: I don't know..
But when I store the page as a HtmlDocument like this:

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb web = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb();
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://www.google.com");

What am I supposed to do then with the "InnerText" as you say??

Comment: @MagnusGlannefors - Did you try `doc.DocumentNode.InnerText`? Did you see what it contains?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [PuppeteerSharp](https://www.puppeteersharp.com/) you can do it without all the HTTP requests.

```
await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision);
var HeadlessBrowser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
    Headless = true
});
var WebPage = await HeadlessBrowser.NewPageAsync();
await WebPage.GoToAsync({URL HERE});
var PageContent = await WebPage.EvaluateExpressionAsync<string>("document.body.innerText");
await HeadlessBrowser.CloseAsync();
Console.WriteLine(PageContent)
```

You can also change the code to make it more streamlined and simple, but this is the basic gist of it.